# QProcess: Start a MATLAB terminal session with input capabilities

Tags: qt, qprocess

I have created a Qt-application, where it should be possible to start a MATLAB session detached in a terminal. The terminal should be either gnome-terminal, xterm or something similar.

I have no problem with just starting a MATLAB session:

```
const QString program = "matlab";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-nodesktop";

// create a qprocess for the matlab process
QProcess myMatlabProcess;

myMatlabProcess.startDetached(program, arguments);
```

I have tried just to add "gnome-terminal -e" in front of the string-expression (where the string-expression is in quotes), but it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?:

```
const QString program = "gnome-terminal";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-e" << "matlab";

// create a qprocess for the matlab process
QProcess myMatlabProcess;

myMatlabProcess.startDetached(program, arguments);
```